# Display returned JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

Im having an issue being able to access the returned object and getting it to display. It is cross domain so I am using jsonp, but can't seem to access the returned object and I don't know why.

```
$(function(){
    var API = "https://ratesjson.fxcm.com/DataDisplayer";
    $.ajax({
        url: API,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        success:function( msg ) {
            var Symbol = msg.Rates.Symbol;
            console.log("Symbol: " +Symbol);
        }
    });
});
```

The data looks like this, and I have no control over how it is formatted or returned:

```
jQuery1102016139126126654446_1458048453204({"Rates":[{"Symbol":"EURAUD","Bid":"1.48741","Ask":"1.48751","Spread":"1.00","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"Copper","Bid":"2.23","Ask":"2.2325","Spread":"2.50","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"AUDNZD","Bid":"1.12279","Ask":"1.12295","Spread":"1.60","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EURSEK","Bid":"9.2382","Ask":"9.23974","Spread":"15.40","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"CADJPY","Bid":"84.603","Ask":"84.609","Spread":"0.60","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDCHF","Bid":"0.98628","Ask":"0.98632","Spread":"0.40","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDCNH","Bid":"6.50553","Ask":"6.50581","Spread":"2.80","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"XAGUSD","Bid":"15.222","Ask":"15.263","Spread":"4.10","ProductType":"5",},{"Symbol":"US30","Bid":"17134.00","Ask":"17136.00","Spread":"2.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"USDSEK","Bid":"8.316","Ask":"8.31711","Spread":"11.10","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"AUDCHF","Bid":"0.73659","Ask":"0.73664","Spread":"0.50","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"GER30","Bid":"9921.00","Ask":"9922.00","Spread":"1.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"USOil","Bid":"36.61","Ask":"36.66","Spread":"5.00","ProductType":"3",},{"Symbol":"GBPNZD","Bid":"2.13329","Ask":"2.13358","Spread":"2.90","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EURCAD","Bid":"1.48262","Ask":"1.48272","Spread":"1.00","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EURUSD","Bid":"1.11089","Ask":"1.1109","Spread":"0.10","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"XPTUSD","Bid":"956.60","Ask":"959.70","Spread":"31.00","ProductType":"5",},{"Symbol":"EURJPY","Bid":"125.441","Ask":"125.449","Spread":"0.80","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"AUS200","Bid":"5089.00","Ask":"5091.00","Spread":"2.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"EURGBP","Bid":"0.78286","Ask":"0.7829","Spread":"0.40","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDCAD","Bid":"1.33461","Ask":"1.33471","Spread":"1.00","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EURNOK","Bid":"9.48035","Ask":"9.48285","Spread":"25.00","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"GBPCHF","Bid":"1.39949","Ask":"1.39961","Spread":"1.20","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"GBPAUD","Bid":"1.89993","Ask":"1.90006","Spread":"1.30","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDJPY","Bid":"112.919","Ask":"112.923","Spread":"0.40","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDNOK","Bid":"8.5339","Ask":"8.5353","Spread":"14.00","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"AUDCAD","Bid":"0.99675","Ask":"0.99684","Spread":"0.90","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"ITA40","Bid":"18746.00","Ask":"18766.00","Spread":"20.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"FRA40","Bid":"4458.50","Ask":"4459.50","Spread":"1.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"AUDUSD","Bid":"0.74683","Ask":"0.74686","Spread":"0.30","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDHKD","Bid":"7.75917","Ask":"7.75948","Spread":"3.10","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"NZDCHF","Bid":"0.65595","Ask":"0.65607","Spread":"1.20","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EURTRY","Bid":"3.21593","Ask":"3.21737","Spread":"14.40","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"AUDJPY","Bid":"84.333","Ask":"84.339","Spread":"0.60","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDZAR","Bid":"15.90479","Ask":"15.9158","Spread":"110.10","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"Bund","Bid":"161.49","Ask":"161.52","Spread":"3.00","ProductType":"4",},{"Symbol":"USDMXN","Bid":"17.88412","Ask":"17.88669","Spread":"25.70","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDTRY","Bid":"2.8947","Ask":"2.89508","Spread":"3.80","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDOLLAR","Bid":"12022.00","Ask":"12024.00","Spread":"2.00","ProductType":"7",},{"Symbol":"JPN225","Bid":"16926.50","Ask":"16936.50","Spread":"10.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"HKG33","Bid":"20290.00","Ask":"20300.00","Spread":"10.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"UK100","Bid":"6136.00","Ask":"6137.00","Spread":"1.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"CADCHF","Bid":"0.73895","Ask":"0.73904","Spread":"0.90","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"NAS100","Bid":"4353.00","Ask":"4354.00","Spread":"1.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"ZARJPY","Bid":"7.097","Ask":"7.10","Spread":"0.30","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"GBPCAD","Bid":"1.89381","Ask":"1.894","Spread":"1.90","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"NGAS","Bid":"1.8745","Ask":"1.8845","Spread":"10.00","ProductType":"3",},{"Symbol":"ESP35","Bid":"8995.00","Ask":"9003.00","Spread":"8.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"GBPUSD","Bid":"1.41899","Ask":"1.41906","Spread":"0.70","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"SPX500","Bid":"2007.63","Ask":"2008.13","Spread":"5.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"GBPJPY","Bid":"160.231","Ask":"160.244","Spread":"1.30","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"XPDUSD","Bid":"561.70","Ask":"564.70","Spread":"30.00","ProductType":"5",},{"Symbol":"EUSTX50","Bid":"3060.00","Ask":"3061.00","Spread":"1.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"TRYJPY","Bid":"38.986","Ask":"39.003","Spread":"1.70","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"NZDCAD","Bid":"0.88767","Ask":"0.8878","Spread":"1.30","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EURNZD","Bid":"1.67013","Ask":"1.67029","Spread":"1.60","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"XAUUSD","Bid":"1231.13","Ask":"1231.55","Spread":"42.00","ProductType":"5",},{"Symbol":"NZDUSD","Bid":"0.66508","Ask":"0.66516","Spread":"0.80","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"SUI20","Bid":"7960.00","Ask":"7964.00","Spread":"4.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"NZDJPY","Bid":"75.101","Ask":"75.108","Spread":"0.70","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"UKOil","Bid":"38.98","Ask":"39.03","Spread":"5.00","ProductType":"3",},{"Symbol":"CHFJPY","Bid":"114.488","Ask":"114.494","Spread":"0.60","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EURCHF","Bid":"1.0957","Ask":"1.09574","Spread":"0.40","ProductType":"1",}]});
```

Everything returnes 'undefined'. [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5o9q8g0y/1/)

Comment: You've got an array of objects, `console.log(msg.Rates[0].Symbol)` should display the first value.

Comment: may be error in json response.

Answer (score 1):

Your response is returning an array of objects.  Iterating over that array should give you the data.  Something like this could work:

```
$(function(){
    var API = "https://ratesjson.fxcm.com/DataDisplayer";
    $.ajax({
        url: API,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        success:function( msg ) {
            var html = '';
            var Symbol = msg.Rates.Symbol;
            for(var i = 0; i < msg.Rates.length; i ++) {
                html += '<tr><td>'+msg.Rates[i].Symbol+'</td><td>'+msg.Rates[i].Bid+'</td><td>'+msg.Rates[i].Ask+'</td><td>'+msg.Rates[i].Spread+'</td></tr>';
                console.log("Symbol: " +msg.Rates[i].Symbol);
            }
            $('#dataTable tbody').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/5o9q8g0y/2/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :

```
var Symbol = msg.Rates[0].Symbol;
console.log(JSON.stringify(Symbol));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
$(function(){
    var API = "https://ratesjson.fxcm.com/DataDisplayer";
    $.ajax({
        url: API,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        success:function( msg ) {
           $.each(msg.Rates, function ( key, value )
             {
                console.log(key +":"+ value);
             });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hi, i edited my answer. by using `d` i wanted to mean the array object which is `Rates` in here.